# Error! Twitter not Conecting from my IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

i m using `AddThis SDK` for facebook,twitter and Email share, facebook and Email is nicely working while Twitter is giving error while conecting from my Iphone.  
 it nice work from my simulator but from iphone twitter not connecting and just display a message in console`"Error!"` 
 code:  
 `[AddThisSDK setTwitterViaText:@"QuotesApp"];`  
    `[AddThisSDK shareURL:@"http://HazratAliQuotes.com"
             withService:@"twitter"  title:string description:@"QuotesApp"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/) to implement Twitter in your application for previous version of iOS

The Previos API of twitter is known as MGTTwitter

For AddThis:

To use Twitter OAuth-enabled sharing, you'll need to tell the library to do so, and then configure your Twitter consumer key, consumer secret, and callback URL.

```
[AddThisSDK setTwitterAuthenticationMode:ATTwitterAuthenticationTypeOAuth];
[AddThisSDK setTwitterConsumerKey:@"yourconsumerkey"];
[AddThisSDK setTwitterConsumerSecret:@"yourconsumersecret"];
[AddThisSDK setTwitterCallBackURL:@"yourcallbackurl"];
```

Below is the new answer added.

Remove the line `[AddThisSDK setTwitterViaText:@"QuotesApp"];`

Add the line `[AddThisSDK setTwitterAuthenticationMode:ATTwitterAuthenticationTypeOAuth];`

and on twitter button pressed create a selector and add the following code as

```
[AddThisSDK shareURL:@"http://www.addthis.com"
             withService:@"twitter"
                   title:@"AddThis - The #1 Bookmarking & Sharing Service"
             description:@"AddThis is a free way to boost traffic back to your site by making it easier for visitors to share your content."];
```

Comment: -@sanchitsingh i have already added all of these step and its working nice from IOS simulator 5.0 and 4.3 but when i trying to connect from my IPhone 4s then it give error Just `Error!!` and not connecting.

Comment: @ShaheenRehman Do one thing, Configure your twitter in your iPhone4S Device Settings. Then try again.

Comment: @ShaheenRehman Check this link to know how to configure twitter in iOS 5. http://www.imore.com/2011/10/21/set-twitter-account-ios5/

Comment: but requirement is IOS 4. -@sanchitsingh i m getting problem in IOS4 while connecting to Twitter. thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I am sure it will work in iOS 4. It was not working in iOS 5 only because of the twitter configuration required in that. Try connecting it in iOS 4 or previous iOS versions. If you get any problem then try the link which I have mentioned in my answer at the top.

Comment: -@sanchitsingh i think i m not explaining my question correctly.  <br/> Problem is that when i check this on simulator it work on both simulator 5 and 4.3, but my device(IPhone) is 4.3 when i click on twitter share button it just give error. `the above link is about ios 5 but in ios 4 there is no twitter setting`

Comment: @ShaheenRehman You need to debug your app while running it in your device and connected with xCode. Put Breakpoints and check the data you are sending and getting from twitter and AddThisSDK

Comment: -@sanchitsingh when i set authenticationMode to Default then it working nice but requirement is OAuth. `with OAuth it create problems` please help

Comment: @ShaheenRehman Ok, I think now I got your problem. ATTwitterAuthenticationType is to be set as default if you want to use ADDThisSDK methods and OAuth if you want to use Twitter methods. What you are doing is, you are setting it as OAuth and using AddThisSDK methods. Mark it - "If you are setting it as OAuth then you need to use twiiter API methods for sharing. If you mark it as default then you can use AddThisSDK methods." For more info Check http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381273-addthis-for-ios-documentation#key-setup

Comment: sorry for asking stupid questions again and again but can you explain the above statement, i m confused not understand the question. this is my code for sharing     `[AddThisSDK setTwitterViaText:@"QuotesApp"];
[AddThisSDK shareURL:@"http://HazratAliQuotes.com" withService:@"twitter" title:string description:@"QuotesApp"];`

Comment: @ShaheenRehman Ok, Last try to resolve your problem. I have added something to the answer above. Try it and tell me whether it is working or not.

Comment: -@sanchitsing same issue, thanks for your help i think i should try another SDK, Thanks a lot for your Help

Comment: -@sanchising i think there is some issue in `             withService:@"twitter"` when i leave blank this then it work but the problem is that it display different option where to share(facebook,twitter email etc...) but with twitter it give error. i see from the site the keyword is twitter for Twitter service but again not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is optional answer for you. In **IOS 5 there is framework Tweeter.Framework.** add this Framework and import, i use this for uploading a image(as a link) and message. may be it's helpful for you.:)

## import "Twitter/Twitter.h"

and on Button Click..

```
- (void)postImageOnTweeterWall
{

if (imageView.image)
{
 
    NSLog(@"tweetbutton pressed called");
    // Create the view controller
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    // Optional: set an image, url and initial text
    [twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"]];
    // [twitter addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"http://MobileDeveloperTips.com/"]]];
    [twitter setInitialText:@"Tweet from iOS 5 app using the Twitter framework."];

    // Show the controller
    [self presentModalViewController:twitter animated:YES];

    // Called when the tweet dialog has been closed
    twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) 
    {
        NSString *title = @"Tweet Status";
        NSString *msg; 
    
        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        msg = @"Tweet compostion was canceled.";
        else if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
        msg = @"Tweet composition completed.";
    
        // Show alert to see how things went...
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    
        // Dismiss the controller
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
}
else
{   UIAlertView  *alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tweeter" message:@"Select photo to Upload" 
                                                             delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        
        [alertView show];
        
   
    
}
```

}

Comment: actually my app requirement is IOS 4.0 so that's why i think i can't use it. thanks for your help